# Call macros with interval between

Tags: vba

I am calling macros via VBA code.

```vb
Sub Button1_Click()
    Call moveFilesFromListPartial
    Call moveFilesFromListPartial_AA
    Call moveAllFilesInDateFolderIfNotExist
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "Button1_Click"
End Sub
```

All the macros run after one minute.

I want the third macro `moveAllFilesInDateFolderIfNotExist` to run after 5 seconds of first two macros. i.e. first two macros should be run after 60 seconds and third macro should be run after 65 seconds. This should be the loop every time.

Comment: How long does it take for `moveFilesFromListPartial` and `moveFilesFromListPartial_AA` to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this maybe:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "Part1"
End Sub

Sub Part1()
    Call moveFilesFromListPartial
    Call moveFilesFromListPartial_AA
    'wait 5sec before running the next part 
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "Part2"
End Sub

Sub Part2()
    Call moveAllFilesInDateFolderIfNotExist
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "Part1"
End Sub
```

Comment: Dear @TimWilliams Sorry that i could not explain my question well. The provided macro by you still needs some changes. The requirement is that the first two macros "moveFilesFromListPartial"       "moveFilesFromListPartial_AA" should run first at defined time i.e. after 60 seconds and after the both macros executed  the third macro "moveAllFilesInDateFolderIfNotExist" which is basically to move files into Archive folder should start execution after 5 seconds.

Comment: the reason of 5 second wait is because the first two macros should complete their processes fairly well and then files should get move to Archive. The first 2 macros takes approximately 2 to 3 seconds to execute. Therefore i want the third macro to wait for few seconds and then it should run.

Comment: The code doesn't do that?  Granted it does run Part1 right away the first time, but after that Part1 should run 60sec after Part2 is finished.  What exactly is the problem you're seeing?

Comment: let me explain,. the first two macros  actually copies the files to sub folders from SOURCE FOLDER, however the source folder receives files from multiple users. Therefore if all 3 macros runs at same time, it sometimes move the files to Archive (which is 3rd macro) before running the first 2 macros (i.e. copying the files to subfolder. This only happens when more than 500 files are copying in source folder.

Comment: for this reason i would like that the first 2 macros should run after 60 seconds and third macro should run after 65 seconds. This way the whole process of copying and archiving will be done smoothly and completely even user sends more than 500 files

Comment: In the current situation there is no change in process. the files from source folder is copying to sub folders (via first 2 macros) and then to Archives (via third macro) exactly at the same time

Comment: I added a minute's delay for the first two macros, but to be honest I think my code does what I *think* you're saying you want: the first two run, then the code sets a 5-sec timer to run the third one.  After the third one is done it loops back to Part1 with a 1-minute delay.

Comment: How *exactly* are you moving these files?  Is it happening asynchronously?

Comment: exactly you have understood the concept correct, but the code is not doing this , all 3 macros are still running at same time. the third macro which is basically to move files into archive is still running parallel with first 2 macros

Comment: OK I have no idea why that would be.  Unless you have multiple `OnTime` runs scheduled after all your testing.

Comment: let me change some sequence in your code and i will revert. the sequece of calling macros should be that first 2 macros runs after 60 seconds and after completion of first 2 macros the third one starts

Comment: i was doing one mistake in my own process,. otherwise the code you have provided is exactly working perfect. bundle of thanks sir

Answer (score 1):

if my understanding is correct, you want to execute macro #3 5 seconds after the 2 first ones where executed.

I suggest to use the  `Application.Wait` method to help you do this:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Call moveFilesFromListPartial
    Call moveFilesFromListPartial_AA
    Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")) ' 5 seconds to wait
    Call moveAllFilesInDateFolderIfNotExist
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "Button1_Click"
End Sub
```

You could also import the `Sleep` method by writing

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwmilliseconds As Long)
```

at the beginning of you module, then calling `Sleep 5000` before calling `moveAllFilesInDateFolderIfNotExist`

Hope this helps